# I have parsed all "href" links from a webpage. I want to open only one of them with my browser. How can I do that?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I want to parse the links that contain a word 'cricket' in it.
Here is the code.

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser
url = "http://www.thehindu.com/"
def hi():
    dep = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dep, "html.parser")
    #to parse links that contain word bangladesh in it
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("bangladesh")):
        tip = link.get('href')
        print(tip)
        webbrowser.open(tip)
hi()
```

[This is the output. And I want to open the 2nd link of my output (and ignore the 1st one) with my webbrowser][1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPkZi.png

Comment: uncomment this `'''webbrowser.open(tip)'''`

Comment: I know that. But If I want to open the 5th link of the result, What should I do?

Comment: post a sample input along with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the second link, you can do:

```
for pos, link in enumerate(soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("bangladesh"))):
    tip = link.get('href')
    print(tip)
    if (pos + 1) == 2:
        webbrowser.open(tip)
```

[Docs on `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I need.